# Notification - LED lights not showing up

Tags: android

For some reason I dont get the LED on my device to show up on notifications anymore:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "myNotification")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setContentTitle(msgTitle)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msgContent))
                .setContentText(msgContent)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setLights(Color.CYAN, 2000, 2000)

                .setAutoCancel(true);

        notificationManager.notify(1234, builder.build());
```

The notification itself is showing up correctly, it's just the LED lights not working.

Yes, my screen is off when the notifications triggers and the LED on my phone is working with other apps as well.

Comment: When you set up your `"myNotification"` channel, did you call [enableLights](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html#enableLights(boolean)) and [setLightColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html#setLightColor(int))? The channel is what is used on API 26+ devices.

Comment: I only set `"myNotification"` because the constructor without that second argument is deprecated. I don't use `NotificationChannel` because my app's Min SDK Version is 19 and this class was added in 26.

Comment: Are you testing on an API 26+ device? If so, you need to create a channel when `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` is 26 or higher.

Comment: I've been testing on an API 24 device